# Using A Variable Inside Firestore Call - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to use a variable inside a Firestore reference. I have a sub-collections stored on the database per shop and they all have the format 'menu Shop1' or 'menu Shop2'. I have to store it this way otherwise if I use menu alone, the collectionGroup reference points to all the menus and returns them all at once - which is not what I want.

I'm struggling to pass the name of the shop to the collectionGroup reference.

This does not work:

```
let shopName = String("Shop1")
let collectionRef = String("menu \(shopName!)")

let ref = db.collectionGroup((collectionRef!))
```

But then this works:

```
let ref = db.collectionGroup("menu Shop1")
```

I have tried all the variations I know and it still wont pass the string. Does anybody know how to fix this? I'm guessing its a small tweek!

Comment: When I paste your code in the Swift playground it says that it "cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'String'" in `String("menu \(shopName!)")`. Since `shopName` is indeed not an optional, that should not have an `!` in there.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your response. It doesn't work with or without the unwrapping.

Comment: Is it possible to pass a string as argument or does the argument need to be hard coded?

Comment: Firestore shouldn't even be seeing the interpolated string. Swift resolves the interpolation before it reaches Firestore, which is why I tested it in the Swift playground. Can you reproduce the problem without a call to Firestore?

Answer (score 0):

I would just concatenate the string like so:

```
let shopName: String = "Shop1"
let refString: String = "menu " + shopName
let ref = db.collectionGroup(refString)
```

Don't forget the 'space' after "menu"

You could also simplify further like so:

```
let shopName: String = "Shop1"
let ref = db.collectionGroup("menu " + shopName)
```

The argument does not need to be hard coded...

Comment: I seem to have found the problem; the shopName is in an array that is passed to the new class using perform(Seque). The function I use to load the data (loadData) I called in viewDidLoad, meaning that the shop name is still blank when I make the call to loadData. I still have the same issue when I move the loadData to viewDidAppear, does anyone know where I can call the function so that the shopName can be obtained before the loadData() function is called?

Comment: Use the completion handler that comes with the database call. This will be triggered once the call is finished and will either return a non nill error (if there was an issue, say bad internet connection) or return good data with a nill error

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for specifying 'String'

```
let shopName = String("Shop1")
```

Just make it

```
let shopName = "Shop1"
```

Then this is not correct if the intention is to actually create a ref to a collection

```
let collectionRef = String("menu \(shopName!)")
```

it should be

```
let shopsCollection = db.collection("shops")
```

or like this

```
let shopName = "shop1"
let thisShop = "menu " + shopName
let shopsCollectionGroup = db.collectionGroup(thisShop)
```

But... I am not sure you're using the collectionGroups correctly to start with based on the names you're using.

A collection group consists of all collections with the same ID, so for example you could have a collection group of 'shops' whereas yours is called 'menu Shop1' which would indicate a single shop. Or from the guide a collectionGroup called 'landmarks' which would include landmarks from multiple cities.

Read though the [Collection Group Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) guide again to ensure it's being used correctly.

As a side note, please protect your code by handling optionals properly.

```
shopName!
```

is bad news is shopName is nil as it will crash you code. See nil-coelescing operators, guard and if statements.